# How do I define the number variable in this function?

Tags: python

I don't really know anything about user defined functions and I am wondering how do I define the number variable in this function?

```
def getNumber(str,input,number):
    number= str(input("Give me a number!:"))
if (number.isdigit())==True:
    print("Thats a great number I love "+str(number))
while (number.isdigit())==False:
    number=str(input("You lied to me thats not a number! Give me a number!"))
getNumber(number)
```

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.  `number` seems clearly defined inside your function.  Could you clear up what you are asking? Could you also fix the indentation in your code? It should be as easy as copy-paste, highlight and press `{}`

Comment: What do you exactly wants, please explain...

Comment: It gives this back as an error: NameError: name 'number' is not defined

Comment: Please provide the necessary information. This question seems very unclear!

Answer (score 2):

Why do you even need parameters for your function. Try the below code.

You are clearly defining number in the function.
You are getting the input from the user.
I think that's all you are actually looking for.
Also your function has 3 parameters and you were passing only one as a number and that was not even defined, that's why you got the error. Even if you had defined the variable number, you still would have got the error as you had two more parameters in there which didn't make sense as you don't need them!

```
def getNumber():
    number= str(input("Give me a number!:"))
    if (number.isdigit())==True:
        print("Thats a great number I love "+str(number))
    while (number.isdigit())==False:
        number=str(input("You lied to me thats not a number! Give me a number!"))
getNumber()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, this

```
def getNumber(str,input,number):
    number= str(input("Give me a number!:"))
if (number.isdigit())==True:
    print("Thats a great number I love "+str(number))
while (number.isdigit())==False:
    number=str(input("You lied to me thats not a number! Give me a number!"))
getNumber(number)
```

is very different to this

```
def getNumber(str,input,number):
    number= str(input("Give me a number!:"))
    if (number.isdigit())==True:
        print("Thats a great number I love "+str(number))
    while (number.isdigit())==False:
        number=str(input("You lied to me thats not a number! Give me a number!"))
getNumber(number)
```

When you run the first version, the third line containing `if (number.isdigit()` is not part of your function - it's not indented, so is actually outside the function and at the root of your module.

This means that when you run your module you are working on a variable (the `number` variable) which hasn't been declared and doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can define any value to a variable by `var_name = value`, i.e. `num = 4` or `string = 'A string`.

You want to scan the user input and verify there aren't any non-digit characters in the string (`\D`):

```
import re

def getNumber():
    number= str(input("Give me a number!:"))

    # re (regex module), check for characters in the alphabet
    if re.search('\D',number) != None:
        return False # or use re module to remove unwanted characters by using re.replace().
    else:
        if '.' in number:
            return float(number)
        else:
            return int(number)
```

**Note** The way this is written, when the function is called it will ask the user for input. If you want to check whether an input is a number, without calling user input inside the function, give the function a parameter that it will check. i.e.

```
import re

def getNumber(input):

    # re (regex module), check for characters in the alphabet
    if re.search('\D',number) != None:
        return False # or use re module to remove unwanted characters by using re.replace().
    else:
        if '.' in input:
            return float(input)
        else:
            return int(input)

>>> getNumber('a3')
False
>>> getNumber('3')
3
```

Hope this helps. Be sure to check out the re module docs for more info.

Cheers!